# Listview scrolling

Tags: listview, scroll

I have used list view to display feedback option and used individual relative layout  to display question and displayed options in radio group buttons.
My Problem is If I select option A for question 1 then the same option automatically get selected for some other questions while scrolling. 
I need solution to overcome this problem.
Awaiting for reply.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to view recycling of list views in Android.

Since you don't provide any specific code, I will try to demonstrate it in android-ish style

In your adapter, you should keep a list "in memory" with user selected answers.

```java
ArrayList<int> answers = new ArrayList<int>();
```

When a user selects an option(onClick()?) save that option in the appropriate position of the answers List

```java
answers.add(position, selectedAnswer);
```

In your adapters getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) use the position to properly populate your answer view like so

```java
convertView.findViewById(R.id.answer_view).setAnswer(answers.get(position));
```